# How to assign words with spaces as a whole name to variable in shell script?

Tags: shell, shell-script

I need to make some directory of Author name.
It's easy when doing them alone. I can simply

```
mkdir "Mario Luis Garcia"
```

This will create one directory named "Mario Luis Garcia"

But when trying do it massively with shell script, I failed.

```
for i in "Mario Luis Garcia" "etc.";
    do 
        mkdir $i
    done;
```

This will create 4 separate directories instead of 2.
I tried to use `{}`, `()`to enclose the quoted text in. Doesn't work.

How to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to quote the variable expansion in double quotes:

`mkdir "$i"`

(Using single quotes `'$i'` would create a directory named `$i`)

If the names can start with `-`, you should also add `--` after the last option argument, indicating that all other arguments are not options, which means in this case they are  directory names:

`mkdir -- "$i"`

Or, with option `-v` (verbose) for example:

`mkdir -v -- "$i"`

Comment: Seigel note that `-p` flag denotes ignore errors and creates dirs as needed. From help: `-p, --parents     no error if existing, make parent directories as needed`

Comment: @Simply_Me Right, the idea was to have an option in the example to show the order of options before `--`. Yes, may be confusing, I'll sinplify.

Comment: yeah, IDK if OP is aware of it, so just thought of making it crystal clear. Thanks for the rapid reply.